# Minor problem in an exercise concerning linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

This is the first exercise in Peter Lax's *"Functional Analysis"*. He claimed that

> The sum of any collection of linear subspaces $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a linear subspace $S$. ($I$ is the index set)

And we need to verify $\forall \alpha,\beta\in S$, $\alpha+\beta\in S$.It seems trivial since we can decompose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$ as well as $\{\beta_j\}_{j\in I}$, where $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in S_i$, we can simply rearrange the summation and get the desired result.  We all know the Riemann rearrangement theorem, so rearrangement of series should be checked carefully. But the problem is, I cannot prove that the rearrangement of the $\alpha_i$'s is convergence or converge to the same value. In the general linear space, no norm or metric is defined, so I cannot find something to control the convergence. Maybe I have overestimated this problem?

Comment: If you're talking *linear algebra*, any element in $\;\sum_{i\in I}S_i\;$ is a **finite** expression $\;s_{i_1}+\ldots+ s_{i_k}\;,\;\;s_{i_m}\in S_{i_m}\;$ . If you allow *infinite sums* then it is because you have some kind of analytic structure in your linear space (Banach, Hilbert or whatever spaces)...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Lax mentioned that his book is about space with infinite dimensions. I was just stuck here since he doesn't say anything about Banach,Hilbert or anything else in the first chapter. He just talked about the linear space axioms. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: My above comment remains for any kind of dimension, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, I've seem your point. Sorry for my misinterpretation. You can make it an answer so that I could accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking linear algebra (finite or infinite dimensional), any element in the subspace

$$\;\sum_{i\in I}S_i\;,\;\;S_i\;\;\text{a vector subspace}\;\;\forall\,i\in I$$

is a finite expression of the form

$$s_{i_1}+…+s_{i_k}\;,\;\;s_{i_m}∈S_{i_m}$$

If you allow infinite sums then it is because you have some kind of analytic structure in your linear space (Banach, Hilbert or whatever spaces)...